# Symfony Process - execute command from service

Tags: php, symfony, process, console, command

How can I run a command (app/console execute:my:command)
in a service via new Process?

I try this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;

$process = new Process(
    'app/console execute:my:command'
);
$process->start();
```

But nothing happens ...
If I call it manually via terminal it works:

```
app/console execute:my:command
```

What am I doing wrong?

> EDIT - Solution: We need to write the whole path. In my case:
>
> ```
> ($this->kernelRootDir is : %kernel.root_dir%)
> ```

```
$processString = sprintf(
    'php %s/../app/console %s %s',
    $this->kernelRootDir,
    self::MY_COMMAND,
    $myArgument
);

$process = new Process($processString);
$process->start();

if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
    throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to add path to PHP cli behind app/console ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is pretty much all you need to do really. I always set the working directory and assume this is needed so that the Symfony command is run from the root of the project

```
$process = new Process(
    'app/console execute:my:command'
);
$process->setWorkingDirectory(getcwd() . "../");

$process->start();
```

For debugging purposes I generally set

```
$process->setOptions(['suppress_errors' => false]);
```

as well

Answer (score 0):

I can't get the `setWorkingDirectory` function to work properly on Windows...

The `fromShellCommandline` function works better for me on Windows with Symfony >= 4.4:

```
$cmd = sprintf('php %s/bin/console %s', 
    $this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir'), 
    'app:my:command'
);

Process::fromShellCommandline($cmd)->run();
```

Hope this will help someone else!